# What libraries/services (paid, or free) exist that clean and validate addresses?

Tags: geocode, data-scrubbing

The service or library that cleans the address needs to be callable  from a  custom .NET wrapper service or library. There is no UI requirement to display a map, or  track delivery of a physical  package to a postal address.

https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm is out as an option because the terms of use are restricted to applications supporting the physical delivery of packages.

It seems that both google and Bing have terms of use that restrict application development usage to presentation of maps in a UI.

Here's an example of using google JavaScript library for geocoding address lookups. It seems to work well. Unfortunately I can’t use this, but  looking for something that works nearly as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Robotronic/ayfgT/

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same thing lately, and have a couple of possibilities. Since I don't have my home computer at work, the only one I can remember now is SmartyStreets.com. They give you a small number for free, then you have to pay after that. I have one more, which I can get a little later tonight.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too, but I wasn't impressed.

I had to literally enter St Petersburg, instead of St Pete before it would recognize a St Pete, Fl address

Answer (score 0):

It may be out of your price range, but my company has used [Melissa Data](http://www.melissadata.com/) for quite a while and the only failures were on super-new housing developments. I think they also send us periodic database updates.